# net.tcp port sharing and mono

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, net.tcp

in my self-hosted WCF application I've got a problem using port sharing with mono.
Given the following code, this exception is thrown:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use

and here is my code:

```
NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(myService1);
host1.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService1Contract), tcpBinding, "net.tcp://192.168.0.70:8075/service1");
host1.Open();

ServiceHost host2 = new ServiceHost(myService2);
host2.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService2Contract), tcpBinding, "net.tcp://192.168.0.70:8075/service2");
host2.Open();
```

I already found this bug report here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=277. Unfortunately there was never a response to the last comment.

Like the person who wrote the report, my code works perfectly fine with windows/.net, but on my linux machine using mono 2.10.8.1 (raspberry pi, soft-float Debian) the mentioned exception occurs.

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Comment: Looks like a bug in Mono.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this? Has someone  maybe found any solution for this problem?

Comment: I guess you could go on their irc and ask http://www.mono-project.com/IRC

Comment: Xamarin mostly focuses on Mobile (not Server) these days, so you're out of luck there. There are some consulting companies/freelances that could fix the bug for you, you could hire them. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: Does someone got an idea for a possible workaround?